# Can't find translation of 'drain rod' anywhere

Tags: meaning

leo, linguee, dict.cc, wikipedia (change language), google translate...can't seem to find anything

this is what I mean

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_rods

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to your wikipedia article on german plumbing and diy sites .. Alternatively, I found that to dislodge blockages _Rohrreinigungsspiralen_ are used.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most suitable word would be "Rohrreinigungsstange". (drain cleaning rod)

I found several products using that name. This for example: http://www.ebay.de/itm/Silverline-12-x-Abflussreiniger-Rohrreinigungsstangen-Rohrreinigung-u-o-Zubehoer-/350993775332

I personally never heard of a drain rod in Germany. Never saw one in a tool shop either. We use other things. Like the Rohrreinigungsspirale which is a long flexible shaft with a crank at its end. Nowadays we mainly use tools that utilize pressured water.

Comment: The Rohrreinigungsspirale is a plumber's snake. Afaik it's used on smaller scale blockages.

Answer (score 0):

in Germany you usually find these Tools

[Rohrreinigungsspirale](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohrreinigungsspirale)

Comment: When posting content that is not your own please take notice of the owner's copyright. in your case it clearly states: *"Die Abbildungen auf dieser Seite sind Eigentum der BAHAG AG / Zweigniederlassung Mannheim oder von der BAHAG AG / Zweigniederlassung Mannheim ausschliesslich zum Gebrauch auf dieser Seite zugelassen. "* - this means that the owner did not allow to use their image here. We therefore had to remove this copyright protected content. See https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rohrreinigungsspirale_1_fcm.jpg for an alternative we may use **with attribution**.